# create a table inside a column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Apologies if I am mistaken, but is there any way to create a table inside a column in MySql?

Brief: I have a table named `test_table` which contains a column named name `test_column`. Now I want to create a table inside `test_column`. Is this possible?

Comment: no , you can't do that in MySQL . What you can make is another table and link them using an ID

Answer (score 4):

You would create a "child" table with an id that is referenced in the column of the main table.  You wouldn't create a "table" in a column.

For example

```
Table 1
columm_pk int
column_fk int

table 2
column_pk (this is what goes in table 1)
other columns as needed.
```

then you just join the tables based on that fk id.   You can have multiple fk column in the first table that link to different child tables.    You can also look in to SET data types in MySql although I wouldn't recommend them.

btw,  If your question is MySql specific then you shouldn't use the oracle tags.

Answer (score 1):

No nested tables in MySql, but there is a SET datatype that you can use in a table
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 1):

That approach is not possible. What you are looking for is a second table that is linked using a field in the first table.

Example:

test_table:

```
ID | column1 | some more columns
```

test_table2:

```
table1_ID | column1| column2...
```

You can then access them using `JOIN` commands. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table t1
INNER JOIN test_table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.table1_ID
```

This way you can have multiple rows for each ID in table 1, which has the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in MySQL.

Comment: Might be useful for OP if you include some text detailing why / what is possible

Comment: @Stephen: I want to store check box values in single column,not by appending each value with comma like 2,3,4,.... so on, i interest in an efficient way, can you help me..