# Nested table in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have created a database like this

```
+----------------+------------------+
|   name         | password         |
+----------------+------------------+
|   john         | ********         | 
+----------------+------------------+
|   james        |  &*^^%^          |
+----------------+------------------+
```

Is there any way to create a new table  row by column friend,messages, and message from  for john and james and other those who join my site?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380288/create-a-table-inside-a-column-in-mysql/9380393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add those columns to your table, but putting that kind of information in the user table is a bad idea.

You should **create new tables** and use a JOIN to fetch the data:

First, add an ID column to your existing table.

```
|----------------|------------------|------------------|
|   ID           | user             | password         | 
|----------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Then, create a new table with the wanted columns:

Table friends:

- ID
- USER_ID_FRIEND
- USER_ID_FRIENDEE

Table messages

- ID
- USER_ID_FROM
- USER_ID_TO
- DATE_SENT
- READ
- MESSAGE_TXT

Comment: USER_ID_FREIND***EE***?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
    ADD COLUMN friends TYPE NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need consider your database design to include those features. you'll need to add new tables that have a relation to your usertable. Before starting this I would suggest you learn a bit more about relational database design, if you dont you'll get in trouble later on and will need to start it all over.

take a look [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/04/database-design-create-tables-and.html), looked like a decent tutorial.